# toggle function design in jquery

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

In this **[fiddle](http://jsbin.com/utoyej/18/edit)**, I am trying to show the ul `#chatList` whenever the user clicks on the div `#showUserList` (a small div at top-left of the application) just left side of the application with same height as of the chat application. When the user clicks `#showUserList` again I am trying to hide it. Which I think happening but behind the Chat Application, not left side of it.

And whenever the user clicks on any of the `li` from the `#chatList`, I want to **hide** `#chatList`. which I dont know how to do because to hide it , it need toggle function call (I think so)

And also sometimes the below code is executing after a long time. Which I dont want to happen.

This is what I have tried:

```
var sameWidth = $('#chat-outline').width();
var sameHeight = $('#chat-outline').height();

$('#showUserList').click(function() {
   $('#chatList').toggle('slow', function() {
     $("#chatList").animate({
        position: "absolute",
        width: sameWidth,
        left: sameWidth,
        height:'100%',
        fontSize: "1em"
     }, 1000 );
  });
});
```

**EDIT**: I am trying here and I got some close to the desired result

Please check this link http://jsbin.com/utoyej/34/

Comment: why don't you use jQuery's slideToggle() function, or am I missing something?

Comment: @user1141356 I am new to jQuery so I dont know that.. :)

Comment: wait i'll give you a fiddle :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("h1").on('click',function(){
    $("div#content").slideToggle();
  });

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mAMjT/)

Comment: That looks nice but I cant see the code for it to refer :D Wait I can see that in IE (but not in chrome, maybe some error)

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. It  has exact the same functionality as your code, if you want to style it, just change CSS? Or am i missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/mAMjT/2/

Comment: The width is not fitting to the parent element as you shown in the example above. I am still trying to get it http://jsbin.com/utoyej/24/edit